# Realizar operación con array sin conocer su tamaño

Tags: c, array

Debo implementar una función con el siguiente prototipo:

```
int base10(char *n, int b)
```

el objetivo es que el array pasado como parámetro contiene en cada indice un dígito de un numero en base b, el cual debo retornarse en base 10. Hasta ahora e escrito lo siguiente.

```
int val(char n){
    if(n >= '0' && n<='9'){
        return (int)n;
    }else{
        switch (n) {
            case 'A': return 10;
            case 'B': return 11;
            case 'C': return 12;
            case 'D': return 13;
            case 'E': return 14;
            case 'F': return 15;
            case 'G': return 16;
        }
    }
}

int base10(char *n, int b){
    int tamano,resultado=0;

    tamano = //no se como

    printf("%d", tamano);
    for(int i=0;i<tamano;i++) resultado += val(n[i])*pow(b,i);

    return resultado;
}
```

Para convertir de base x a base 10 debo multiplicar cada digito por la base elevada a su posición en el numero, mi problema es que no se cuantas operaciones debo llevar acabo debido a que no me entregan como información el numero de dígitos (o tamaño del array).

Comment: Si tienes el puntero no puedes obtener el tamaño del array

Comment: Mira este post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array

Comment: Pero mas haya de si se puede o no obtener el tamaño de un array, ¿es posible entonces resolver este ejercicio sin necesidad de conocerlo?

Comment: Es posible, pero debes tener en cuenta que los arrays de char por convención terminan en 0x00

Comment: No, no se puede. Es imposible resolver este problema sin conocer el tamaño del array. Tener en cuenta que los arrays de char por convención terminan en 0x00 es equivalente a conocer el tamaño del array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es posible resolver ese problema sin conocer el tamaño del array. Ya sea de forma directa (te dan el tamaño numérico directamente) o indirecta (el array tiene un terminador como `'\0'`).

Observo que en tu código cada elemento contiene no un número de un dígito en base b, sino un carácter ASCII que representa un dígito en base b.

La distinción es importante porque indica que `char *n` es seguramente una cadena de caracteres standard de C. Y la convención standard en C es usar un terminador `'\0'`.

Por tanto la solución es recorrer el array hasta encontrar un elemento que sea `'\0'`

```
int base10(char *n, int b){
    int resultado=0;
    char *p = n;

    while( *p!='\0' ) {
      resultado = resultado*b + val(*p);
      ++p;
   }
   return resultado;
}
```

El código anterior sufrirá de overflow para números que excedan la capacidad de `int` y tampoco tiene control de errores, pero eso es asunto para otra pregunta.

Por otra parte la función `val` no es correcta.

Si el parámetro `char n` vale '0' el resultado de `(int)n` no es 0 sino que es 48.

El motivo es que n es una variable de tipo char que contiene, por convenio, un número que representa a un carácter según la [tabla de códigos ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/). como puedes ver en la tabla anterior el número 48 representa al carácter `'0'`.

Para convertir de un carácter ASCII a su varlor numérico basta con restar 48.

Y aunque la conversión de las letras 'A' a la 'G' con un switch es correcta se puede hacer con menos código usando la misma técnica.

```
int val(char n){
    if(n >= '0' && n<='9'){
        return (int)(n-'0');
    }else if ( n>='A' && n<='Z' {
        return (int)(n-'A'+10);
    }
    else {
        printf("Cadena incorrecta, no contiene un número");
        abort();
    }
}
```

Aunque la funcion `val` anterior contiene algo de control de errores sigue sin ser sufuciente. El número "JJ019A" no es válido en base 10 y sí lo es en base 30, pero eso el código anterior no lo detecta.

Comment: Gracias por la info, sabia eso de '\0' pero había leído que no ocurría en todos los casos y no era algo seguro. El tema de control de errores etc no era necesario.